# Mediarecorder IllegalStateException on SetProfile

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mediarecorder

I'm quite a beginner in Xamarin studio, and I'm trying to make a video recording app, but it keeps throwing exceptions.
Here is the code for setting the layout and click-event:

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);
        string path = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/MyCamera/test.mp4";

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        tView = new TextureView(this);
        tView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;
        tView.Click += delegate
        { 
            RecordVideo(path);
        };

        SetContentView(tView);
```

And the record method:

```
public void RecordVideo(string path)
    {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
        mRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
        mRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
        mRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Default);
        mRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);
        mRecorder.SetProfile(CamcorderProfile.Get(CamcorderQuality.High));
        mRecorder.SetOutputFile(path);
        mRecorder.SetMaxDuration (10000);
        mRecorder.Prepare();
        try{
            mRecorder.Start();
        }catch( Exception ex) {
            ex.GetType ();
        }
    }
```

And the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Thanks in advance,
Pineapplez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally worked it out. It turns out that this part:

```
    mRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
    mRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Default);
    mRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);
```

is also contained in the Setprofile method, which causes to set the output format and encoder twice. with an Illegal State Exception as result. Now my code looks like this:

```
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mCamera.Unlock();
    mRecorder.SetCamera(mCamera);
    mRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
    mRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
    mRecorder.SetProfile(CamcorderProfile.Get(CamcorderQuality.High));
    mRecorder.SetOutputFile(path);
    mRecorder.SetMaxDuration (10000);
    mRecorder.Prepare();
    mRecorder.Start();
```

And i have added *mCamera.Unlock();* to allow mRecorder to use it. 
And *mRecorder.SetCamera(mCamera);* to make sure mRecorder uses the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really that into Xamarin, but I think it's because the stream aren't ready yet - so you're calling start too early in the process. Use the PrepareAsync method, then hook up a callback when it's ready, then do the Start().